# How to ping websocket server, so it doesn't disconnect me for being idle

Tags: python, websocket

I'm using [websocket-client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client) to connect to a websocket server.  The server i'm connected to seems to be expecting me to ping it periodically or else it disconnects me.

Right when I connect to the server, it sends me this message:

```
0{"sid":"SomeID","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}
```

This seems to tell me the ping interval and ping timeout.  I noticed that my websocket client is getting disconnected consistently ~1 minute and 25 seconds after I connect.  And if you add up those numbers 60s + 25s you get 1 min and 25 seconds.  So It seems I need to ping this server every so often so it doesn't disconnect me.

How do I ping the server?  I tried `ws.ping()` but that didn't seem to exist.  Do I need to send data to the server in some format it's expecting?  Or is there some built in ping command?

```
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://socket.serverssite.com/socket.io/?transport=websocket",
                                on_message=on_message,
                                on_error=on_error,
                                on_close=on_close)
    ws.run_forever()
```

Note: I made a websocket client in node (not python) and it doesn't get closed after 1 min 25 seconds.  So It seems that has some built in ping that this python websocket client does not...

**------------------------Edit-------------------------**

Tried setting ping_interval and ping_timeout, but it's still closing:

```
2017-11-06 12:49:14.340037--------------------- Doing stuff
2017-11-06 12:49:14.340309--------------------- Doing stuff
send: '\x89\x80\\\xd9\xc4\xdd'
2017-11-06 12:49:19.341680--------------------- Doing stuff
2017-11-06 12:49:19.341958--------------------- Doing stuff
send: '\x89\x80\xd9\x06\xef\xa8' 
2017-11-06 12:49:24.343426--------------------- Doing stuff
2017-11-06 12:49:24.343769--------------------- Doing stuff
send: "\x89\x80\xe6\x92'\xb8" 
send: '\x88\x823\xfb$\xd10\x13' 
closed (Here is where the closed method gets called, the server shut me down)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I'm assuming you have access to the server code as well, right? [This answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47119476/) seems to be a server-side setting.

Answer (score 8):

From the source code -

```
def run_forever(self, sockopt=None, sslopt=None,
                ping_interval=0, ping_timeout=None,
                http_proxy_host=None, http_proxy_port=None,
                http_no_proxy=None, http_proxy_auth=None,
                skip_utf8_validation=False,
                host=None, origin=None)
```

Specifying the `ping_interval` should work for you.

```
ws.run_forever(ping_interval=70, ping_timeout=10)
```

Comment: Thanks.  For some reason the server is still closing it on me.  I wonder if the ping that this library is sending is not what the server is expecting.  I see it sending things like, send: '\x89\x80f\x7fLt' , send: '\x89\x8000\xf8\x85' , send: '\x88\x82-l\xb8\x00.\x84' but it'll still close after that 1 min 25 seconds.

Comment: I'm encountering a similar situation using Python and have tried various solutions in the past several weeks and haven't been able to resolve this. Did you even find an answer?

Comment: @Thomas did you manage to solve it yet? Ideally there would be an option to supply a custom ping message when creating the instance (EG heartbeat_message={"message"="PING"}, I'm at the point of thinking to just fork the project and add it in myself

Comment: @leo_cape, I did modify the code but it didn't help my situation. In my case, it could be due to Python not being able to keep up with the amount of data coming in. I'm planning to have the script run on multiple computers to handle a sub-part of the data coming in to see if it'll help.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, In my case I added an infinite loop with some safeguards that manually sends a message in the ping format the server needs. Feels hacky but doesn't seem to be any other workaround save forking that i can see. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and solved it by pinging the server with 2 using `socket.io`. I was using the asyncio and websockets libraries and just used the following to prevent the websocket from closing:

```
await ws.send('2')
```

Using the standard websocket library will be something similar.

### Full explanation

The server is socket.io This means you need to send a ping message of 2 to the server within the pingTimeout. [From socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-protocol):

> **Encoding - Packet**
>
> An encoded packet can be UTF-8 string or binary data. The packet
> encoding format for a string is as follows
>
> ...
>
> 0 open Sent from the server when a new transport is opened (recheck)
>
> 1 close Request the close of this transport but does not shutdown the
> connection itself.
>
> **2 ping**
> Sent by the client. Server should answer with a pong packet containing
> the same data
>
> ...
>
> **Timeouts**
>
> The client must use the pingTimeout and the pingInterval sent as part
> of the handshake (with the open packet) to determine whether the
> server is unresponsive.
>
> **The client sends a ping packet. If no packet type is received within pingTimeout, the client considers the socket disconnected.** If a pong
> packet is actually received, the client will wait pingInterval before
> sending a ping packet again.
>
> Since the two values are shared between the server and the client, the
> server will also be able to detect whether the client becomes
> unresponsive when it does not receive any data within pingTimeout +
> pingInterval.

Comment: This is not the proper way to ping. Calling ```ws.send( '2' )``` will send the string ```'2'```. You want ```ws.ping( payload )``` where ```payload``` is a random character string.

See: https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/blob/562808fe25f4f922e3422b99eb00aa53d9734ba0/websocket/_core.py#L287

Comment: For me, `ws.send('2')` works on the client side and if I do an other string like `ws.send('test')`, it says `parse error` on the server side.

Comment: This *is* the proper way to ping when using the socket.io protocol (which is a protocol implemented on top of websockets).